# how get the object which has the minimum value in an orderedDict?

Tags: python, object, attributes, ordereddict

I have an orderedDict of objects,

```
 [<f.Packet object at 0x07AD7090>, <f.Packet object at 0x07ACA8F0>, <f.Packet object at 0x07ACAC90>, <f.Packet object at 0x07A5F5D0>, <f.Packet object at 0x07ACA410>, <f.Packet object at 0x07ABBF50>, <f.Packet object at 0x07ACA830>]
```

Each of these objects has attributes such as name, age, and source. How can I  get the object which its age is the minimum one?

Comment: is this an orderedDict or List? code shows list.

Comment: @vinay: the type is <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need, you might use simple traversal:

```
min(orderedDict.values(), key=lambda x: x.age)
```

But if you need a O(1) way to do it, you need to create your own class, because OrderedDict orders items only based on the insertion order. For example, you can use SortedDict from [Sorted Containers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html) (or write your own) and do something like this (assuming you still want to be able to get items based on the insertion order):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
     def __init__(self):
             super(MyOrderedDict, self).__init__(self)
             self.sorted = SortedDict()
     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
             super(MyOrderedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
             self.sorted[value.age] = value
     def __delitem__(self, key):
             age = super(MyOrderedDict, self).__getitem__(key).age
             super(MyOrderedDict, self).__delitem__(key)
             self.sorted.__delitem__(age)
     def ageIterator(self):
         for age in self.sorted:
             yield (age, self.sorted[age])

orderedDict = MyOrderedDict()
#...

for item in orderedDict:
    # Items in the order of insertions

for age, item in orderedDict.ageIterator():
    # Items by age
```

Answer (score 1):

try this once, suppose you have d as orderedDict

```
import operator
#...
person=sorted(d.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('age'))[0]
print person.age
```